# How to upgrade from VS 2017 to 2019?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, upgrade, visual-studio-2019, vsinstaller

VS 2019 is RTM, and I was wondering what's the proper way to upgrade from VS 2017, is there a dedicated 'upgrade' method, or is it uninstall and install? Maybe install and uninstall?
What's the right way to do it without having to uninstall and reinstall same stuff for nothing?

Comment: Install new one since then it won’t need to install what’s already there. Then remove old if you don’t need it.

Comment: VS versions are always side-by-side, there is no "upgrade".  You'd consider uninstalling an older version only if you need the disk space and made sure the new version can properly handle all your existing projects.  Don't be in a hurry about that with VS2019 btw, there will no doubt be many updates in the next year.  Opening a VS2017 solution in VS2019 is rarely a problem either, if it needs to upgrade a project then it will tell you about it.

Comment: @HansPassant, the same applies with Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

We cannot directly upgrade VS 2017 to VS 2019.  They are compatible and work side by side though (like the following).  Please download and install VS 2019 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes 
[image]

Comment: Hi Sara and thanks for your answer. I don't want them side by side, I want to replace 2017 with 2019, should I first install 2019 then uninstall the old one (like the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487397/how-to-upgrade-from-vs-2017-to-2019#comment97683708_55487397) above?

Comment: @Shimmy it's probably the safest bet to make sure 2019 is working correctly (and your projects and solutions open and build successfully) and then Uninstall 2017. All of your settings should sync when you login to your MS account when launching VS for the first time.

Comment: @Shimmy, like others recommended, we can firstly install the VS 2019 to use and sync, if you confirm that VS 2017 is not useful for your development, follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 to remove the VS 2017. If you meet any issues during the uninstall and install process, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I would dedicate a machine to it, or install minimally on a virtual machine to test it out. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Verified the approach. Installed 2019, ran it once to sync the settings, uninstalled 2017. VS2019 retains previously made settings.

Comment: Does Microsoft charged for multiple licenses in a volume licensing environment when you have multiple versions installed side by side?

Answer (score 5):

On Visual Studio Installer, You will see two tabs : Installed and Available. On Installed Tab, Visual Studio Community 2017, Click on More Drop-down, Choose Uninstall. Reboot is recommended before you begin with Installing Visual Studio Community 2019 from Available Tab.